# Center stack view elements and not fill them

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitableview, uistackview

I am using a `UIStackView` as `UITableView's` `BackGroundView` property so when there was an error getting the collection that populates the tableView I can call a function that displays this stack view containing views that show a warning message and a retry button.

I tested doing a similar behaviour in an empty `UIViewController` so I could center the `stackView` and its children. The solution worked when I pinned the stack view to the superView's trailing and leading, centered it vertically and set it's top anchor to be greater or equal to the superView's top anchor and similarly it's bottom anchor is greater or equal to the superView's bottom anchor. I have also set the alignment to center and distribution to fill and all seemed to work properly.

Here are some screenshots: [image]

[image]

[image]

I used this code in a UITableView's extension, but could only reproduce this behaviour. Are there any errors on this code?

```
func show(error: Bool, withMessage message : String? = nil, andRetryAction retry: (() -> Void)? = nil){
    if error{
        let iconLabel = UILabel()
        iconLabel.GMDIcon = .gmdErrorOutline
        iconLabel.textAlignment = .center
        iconLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        iconLabel.font = iconLabel.font.withSize(50)
        iconLabel.textColor = Constants.Colors.ErrorColor

        iconLabel.backgroundColor = .blue

        let messageLabel = UILabel()
        messageLabel.text = message ?? "Ocorreu um erro"
        messageLabel.textColor = Constants.Colors.ErrorColor
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        messageLabel.textAlignment = .center
        messageLabel.font = UIFont(name: "TrebuchetMS", size: 20)

        messageLabel.backgroundColor = .green

        var views: [UIView] = [iconLabel, messageLabel]

        if let retry = retry{
            let button = RaisedButton(title: "Tentar novamente")
            button.pulseColor = Constants.Colors.PrimaryTextColor
            button.backgroundColor = Constants.Colors.PrimaryColor
            button.titleColor = .white
            button.actionHandle(controlEvents: .touchUpInside, ForAction: retry)
            button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10,10,10,10)


            views.append(button)
        }


    }else{
        self.backgroundView = nil
    }
}
let stack = UIStackView()
    stack.spacing = 10
    stack.axis = .vertical
    stack.alignment = .center
    stack.distribution = .fill
    stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


    for view in views{
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.addArrangedSubview(view)
    }

    if self.tableFooterView == nil{
        tableFooterView = UIView()
    }
    self.backgroundView = stack;

    if #available(iOS 11, *) {
        let guide = self.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        stack.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: guide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: guide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        stack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    } else {
        stack.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        stack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stack view knows its height if its elements all have an intrinsic size (ie its the sum of their individual heights + the inter item spacing).  In this case because you have a 2 y position constraints, you are implying a height, so your constraints are unsatisfiable.  The only y axis constraint you need is center vertically.  get rid of the top and bottom constraints.  The system will then use the intrinsic size to compute the height of the stack view and center it vertically in the background view.  Leave your x axis constraints as is.